# Tile Formats Using Formattable in R

Tags: r, rstudio, formattable

What I would like to do is use `color_tile` on a column based on a calculation instead of basing it on it's own continuous scale. I have code to format the color of the text in the following example:

```
library(formattable)

my.df <- data.frame(
   Type = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
   Count = c(5, 7, 3, 8, 4),
   Expect = c(2, 6, 3, 15, 0)
 )

formattable(my.df, list(
  Type = formatter("span",
                   style = ~style(color = ifelse(Count/Expect - 1 > .2, "red", 
    ifelse(Count/Expect - 1 < -.2, "green", "black")))
                   )

  ))
```

Those are the colors I want, but instead of colored text I would like to have tiles. I haven't figured out how I can use `color_tile` that is based on a calculation or based on something other than its own column's values. Can I condition using tiles?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I ended up using the DT package. Here is a link that can show you how to do it.
https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html